# Docker Container Error: OCI runtime create failed: invalid rootfs

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-build, docker-run

I'm new to docker and I'm encountering an error when trying to run a Docker container and access its shell.

I've built an image named "friendnet-client" successfully. The image sets up a Node.js environment based on the `node:20.3.0-alpine3.17` image.

```
FROM node:20.3.0-alpine3.17
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 
RUN npm install
```

When I try to open the shell of the container using the command:

```
docker run -it friendnet-client sh
```

I encounter the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: invalid rootfs: stat /var/run/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/2fba0ba5512bd017e06c3a26b730ca76f9577fe50e5e1b2a24f29604dc011479/E:\my software\Docker\ProgramData/vfs/dir/149ecdeb95fccf2e7d1a4e8b5c60bf912e8d3b8d2ea7b5b7b53ab8220b8bd722: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

Before that, I've tried changing the data-root in my daemon.json configuration file to E:\my software\Docker\ProgramData as my C drive is full. Here's my daemon.json configuration:

```
{
"builder": {
"gc": {
"defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
"enabled": true
}
},
"experimental": false,
"data-root": "E:\\my software\\Docker\\ProgramData"
}
```

However, I'm uncertain whether this adjustment is related to the issue at hand. In the error message, the path appears to use both / and , resembling a search within the Linux file system during the execution of the command.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop?

Comment: Yes, I'm using docker destop

Comment: I don't think that Docker Desktop operates with `daemon.json` in the same was as the CLI client.

Comment: is it better to work without docker desktop ?

Comment: I don't know if that will solve your problem but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If your `C:` drive is full then it's quite likely that some of that space is being consumed by Docker images and containers. This is what I suggest:

1. Revert all changes to `daemon.json` and restart Docker (or Docker Desktop) so that this takes effect.
2. Purge unused images and containers. With Docker CLI you would do this with `docker system prune -a`. I'm not sure what the equivalent would be for Docker Desktop, but there must be an option to delete these.

Comment: I get it, but when I change the data-root to the hard drive it doesn't work I get the same error

Comment: Did you try to free up space on `C:`?

Comment: yes I did and I can run Docker and it works fine, but the C drive where Docker stores containers fills up quickly.  To address this, I'd like to configure Docker to use the E drive for storing containers.